# Migrate jquery project to nextjs, and remove modularisation for each file

Tags: jquery, webpack, next.js

Right now, we have 2 programs running to power one web application. There is a nextjs application which handles about 20% of the application's logic, and a django application serving a jquery-based front-end, which handles the rest. Nextjs uses an iframe to load the django webapp into any pages that require it.

However, we now need to migrate all of the jquery code to the nextjs application, so that the overhead of having an iframe is removed. However, I'm struggling to make webpack compile these jquery files together.

I have had some success in getting the jquery files to load on the web page. By using require.context, I can load multiple javascript files at once, and the code inside these javascript files will execute properly

src/legacy-jquery/index.tsx

```js
function importAll(r) {
    console.log(r.keys());
    r.keys().forEach(r);
}


if (window) {
    const context = require.context("./", true, /\*.js/);
    importAll(context);   
}
```

src/legacy-jquery/test.js

```js
console.log("Test file");
console.log("Checking whether jquery exists");
console.log($);
```

When importing this file in my component, the code does execute correctly, so I am able to see those messages in the console.

```
export default function InvoiceSettings() {
  useEffect(() => {
    import('../../src/legacy-jquery/index');
  }, [])
  return <InvoiceSettingsContainer />;
}
```

However, the problem that I am facing now is related to dependencies between my jquery files. There are many dependencies between these files (in terms of one file using a variable from another file, etc), and while the jquery code from these files does work properly when it has been included, for the application to work correctly, I would have to manually import every single class, variable, function, etc dependency, which is not feasible at the moment. Is there any way that I can have nextjs and webpack compile these files together so that resources are shared freely between the files?

Comment: Why can't you create a master `.js` file that declares all variables, objects, classes etc ..  Only 1 import in the main `App.js` or index file at that point. --  You'll still have to pass through into your components .. But that's more manageable.   IMHO, from personal experience, when doing this sort of project, sometimes it's best to hit the whiteboard and start from scratch.  Then you can take care of other bugs/feature fixes that you've been meaning to get to along the way as well.